# Turtle module Import error on Atom editor

Tags: python, atom-editor

whenever I try to import turtle on Atom... it imports fine but then when I open the launcher to view the output, this happens.

[black screen shows up...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hX5C.png)

here is my code.

```
import turtle as t
for i in range(4):
    t.forward(100)
    t.left(90)

 t.done()
```

Comment: The output from the logs and the traceback from the error would help. A turtle window opens so it doesn't look like you have an issue importing that package

Comment: When I run your code, I get a white window with a black box drawn on it. Maybe for some reason you have a black box on a black window. Try changing the color. `t.pencolor("red")`

Comment: thank you for answering... but the exact same thing occurs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So my problem is that when I try and code anything on Atom editor for the turtle graphics module, no matter what I type, The python launcher window appears black with a small, flickering white box in the corner. This does not happen when i try it on VSCode. What should I do?